# Converting 3D tiles files to i3S format

Tags: 3d-tiles, indexed-3d-scene-layer

My goal is to test and compare the performance of 3D tiles VS i3S in :

- storing large volumes of data (volumetry).
- displaying (data display time)

I have currently 2 larges 3D tiles files. For information, I work on Windows OS.

Is there a way to convert those two 3D tiles to i3S format ?

Comment: Hello, what is the format of 3D tiles?

Comment: 3D-tiles format (Cesium & OGC specifications) : 
https://github.com/CesiumGS/3d-tiles
https://www.ogc.org/standards/3DTiles

Comment: do you have ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Thanks. Personally no. But i can ask to one of my colleagues may be. According to you Arcgis Pro or another tool (like FME) could  make this conversion 3d-tiles to i3S ?

Comment: I succeed in installing Arcgis PRO on my Windows station. Could you tell me how to load 3D tiles format ? And how to convert it toward I3S format ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The OGC Testbed-13: 3D Tiles and I3S Interoperability and Performance ER which does this exact comparison - http://docs.opengeospatial.org/per/17-046.html

Answer (score 2):

loaders.gl provides a two-way converter between 3D Tiles and I3S: https://loaders.gl/modules/tile-converter/docs/cli-reference/tile-converter

Answer (score -1):

Any news about performance comparison between 3d tiles vs i3s to render 3d geospatial ?

I need to render 3d geospatial on a mobile app in flutter. I’d like to know if I should go with 3d tiles rendered on Cesium or VTS technology
or
i3d with “I still don’t what tool to render it”.

I’d like to know if you had the opportunity to compare performances ?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/237281)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour] to better understand how our Focused question/Best answer model operates. You've asked a series of questions in an Answer block, which is likely to result in this Answer being deleted. If you have a new Question, please ask it as a Question.